# How to substitute text into HTML in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of template HTML that is returned from a Javascript function:

```
function getTemplate() {
    return '<li id="element_idx_" class="elementChoice">' +
           '  <a href="#" onclick="_clickScript_" tabindex="27" title="_toolTip_">' + 
           '    <span id="element_idx_title">_elementDisplayText_</span>' + 
           '    <div class="elementIcon" id="element_idx_image"></div>' +
           '    <div class="actionIcon" id="element_idx_Icon"></div>' +
           '  </a>' +
           '</li>';
}
```

The substrings `_idx_`, `_clickScript_`, etc., are substituted using data retrieved from an AJAX call, using a function whose definition is similar to:

```
function interpolate(template, replacements) {
    // * template is the HTML listed above
    // * replacements is a JavaScript object, where the property names map to 
    //   the substitution strings in the HTML template.
    // 
    // E.g., { idx: 4, clickScript: function() { // click }, displayName: foo }
}
```

As you can see, some items are replaced multiple times within the template (i.e., `_idx_`).

The webapp already uses jQuery extensively throughout, so I'm wondering if there's a more jQuery-esque way of achieving this, perhaps using the DOM, rather than relying on string manipulation.

Any thoughts?

Comment: [this](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) might help - or [this plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/micro_template)

Comment: why don't you generate whole template on server side and use ajax to get that template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well John Resig has blogged about putting templates like that into script blocks:

```
<script id='template1' type='text/html'>
  <li id='element_idx' ...
    ...
  </li>
</script>
```

The browsers won't try to interpret those, but you can get the text:

```
var template = $('#template1').text();
```

It's a little cleaner than putting your template in the Javascript like that, but it's not without its problems. Separating the template from the code *might* be a little painful or awkward, depending on your setup.

Comment: Interestingly, we had something similar to this previously, but used $("#template1").html() to retrieve the template.  This broke on IE because of its buggy innerHTML implementation: the quotations around the `a` tag's title attribute were stripped out and broke the tooltip.

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure that using `.text()` (the jQuery method) works in IE.  I know that in IE trying to use `.innerHTML` on some things results in a bizarre "Unknown error" exception - maybe it's `<style>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't since you replace those strings in places that are hard to reach with DOM operations (like `element_idx_Icon`).